# Image not uploaded in Xamarin via API

Tags: xamarin

I have a problem that is still unclear: I am trying to upload an image from Xamarin via the API. I check the code for the OK message, but the image can't be uploaded to the Server, I tried to test the API on Postman, swagger, it works fine. I checked `read_external_storage` and `write_external_storage`

```
async void pickimg_Tapped(System.Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pickResult = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(await pickResult.OpenReadAsync()), "file", pickResult.FileName);
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var responses = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.com/api/UploadFileFeeds", content);
    lb_status.Text = responses.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

[image]

[image]

I check the `responses` value returns OK. However I can't find the image on the Server's folder. Note that when I test on Postman vs swagger, the image is saved on the Server. What did I do wrong? Ask for a solution from everyone

Comment: Have you checked the response message for any other useful information?  Have you looked at the server logs?  Have you read the docs for the API or debugged the server code?

Comment: I think is something in your server. Check the logs or change the destination folder.

Comment: Yes, I will check it again